# R - scale_x_date issue on missing data

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I have this sample of data:

```
sample <- data.frame(service_type = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),
                     qty = c(38,185,87,29,12,133,2,14,31,2,9,59,60,43,137,135,31,159,15,32,1,25,60,100,30,40,50),
                     year_week = c("2023 - CW48","2023 - CW48","2023 - CW48","2023 - CW49","2023 - CW49","2023 - CW49","2023 - CW50","2023 - CW50","2023 - CW50","2023 - CW51","2023 - CW51","2023 - CW51","2023 - CW52","2023 - CW52","2023 - CW52","2024 - CW01","2024 - CW01","2024 - CW01","2024 - CW02","2024 - CW02","2024 - CW02",'2024 - CW03','2024 - CW03','2024 - CW03','2024 - CW04','2024 - CW04','2024 - CW04'),
                     xlabel2 = c("Nov-23","Nov-23","Nov-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Dec-23","Jan-24","Jan-24","Jan-24","Jan-24","Jan-24","Jan-24","Jan-24","Jan-24","Jan-24","Jan-24","Jan-24","Jan-24")
)

sample <- sample %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0(year_week, 1), "%Y - CW%U%u"))
```

As you can see I miss the data for CW53-2023 and the date field jumps from 25/12/2023 to 08/01/2024; when I plot the data the date_breaks option creates a week 2024-CW00 with no data.
See below the code for plot and the plot itself. Any idea how to remove that week?

```
ggplot(sample ) +
  
  aes(x = date, y = qty, fill = service_type) +
  
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  
  geom_line(aes(group = 1), stat = "summary", fun = sum, linetype = "dashed", size = 1, color = '#FF507B') +
  geom_point(aes(group = 1), stat = "summary", fun = sum, size = 2, color = '#FF507B') +
  
  geom_text(aes(label=qty), 
            position=position_dodge(7 * 0.9), vjust = 0)+
  
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(y), group = 1),
            stat = "summary", fun = sum, vjust = 0, size = 3) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(A = "#FFC000", B = "#92D050", C = "#AE5AFF"))+
  scale_x_date(
    date_labels = "%Y - CW%U",
    date_breaks = "1 week",
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      breaks = as.Date(paste0("15-", unique(sample$xlabel2)), "%d-%b-%y"),
      labels = \(x) format(x, "%b-%y")
    )
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "left",
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: What's the source and most likely locale for those `year_week` values?  `%U` in `"%Y - CW%U%u"` is for US convention, *Sunday as the first day 1 of the week (and typically with the first Sunday of the year as day 1 of week 1)*  (from `?strftime`) , with your data it results with a 1 week gap between "2024-01-08" and "2024-01-15".

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`ggbreak`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/index.html). I'll break ffrom `"2023-12-25"` to `"2024-01-08"`.

```r
gg <- ggplot(...) # your code unmodified
gg +
  ggbreak::scale_x_break(breaks = as.Date(c("2023-12-25", "2024-01-08")))
```

[image: basic ggbreaks, distorted]

This clearly distorts the x-axis, so we can buffer it a bit; not sure if we can automate this "perfectly".

```r
gg +
  ggbreak::scale_x_break(breaks = as.Date(c("2023-12-25", "2024-01-08")) + c(1.5, -1.5))
```

[image: ggbreak, improved]

The biggest "huh?" about that is that the red dashed line is broken (clear to understand why) and the two stubs do not appear to intersect. I believe this is "by intent", meaning the `ggbreak` package intends to break-up the geometries/layers that span the gap.